# How to compute numbers in each line of a file python?

Tags: python-3.x

In my file, I have in each line numbers that are between 0 and 256:

```
20
123
125
109
175
108
210
74
127
86
172
128
187
131
183
230
132
77
30
177
64
60
211
112
79
45
```

I would like to compute how many each number is repeated  in this file:

```
with open('file', 'w') as f_sb_out:
    for i in range(256):
        total = sum(str(i))
        print('Numre of repetition of '+str(i)+'is', str(total))
```

Comment: Instead of `for i in range(256):` you can do `for line in f_sb_out:`
This will give you each line and you can do whatever you want with it. Also, are you trying to sum all the numbers or are you trying to find how many unique occurrences of a number there are?

Comment: @bhow I want to compute the occurences of each number.

Comment: To keep track of unique occurrences and to not get too crazy I would suggest a dictionary. You can do: `if dict.get(line): dict[line]++ else: dict[line] = 1` for each iteration of your loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is certainly not the best way of doing it in terms of error handling, but it meets your basic requirements.

```
# Declare dict for counts
numCount = dict()

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f_sb_out: # Need to change the form to read, not write
    line = f_sb_out.readline()          # Read the first line
    while line:                         # Loop through each line
        line = f_sb_out.readline()
        line = line.strip()             # Strip any whitespace on either end
        if line == '':                  # Skip any whitespace lines
            continue
        if line in numCount:
            numCount[line] = numCount[line] + 1  # Increment the counter
        else:
            numCount[line] = 1          # Start a new counter

# Print the counts
for num in numCount:
    print "The number " + num + " appeared "+ str(numCount[num]) + " time(s)."
```

Given your file, it produces:

```
The number 210 appeared 1 times.
The number 211 appeared 1 times.
The number 60 appeared 1 times.
The number 132 appeared 1 times.
The number 131 appeared 1 times.
The number 64 appeared 1 times.
The number 112 appeared 1 times.
The number 177 appeared 1 times.
The number 175 appeared 1 times.
The number 230 appeared 1 times.
The number 172 appeared 1 times.
The number 79 appeared 1 times.
The number 86 appeared 1 times.
The number 45 appeared 1 times.
The number 183 appeared 1 times.
The number 187 appeared 1 times.
The number 77 appeared 1 times.
The number 108 appeared 1 times.
The number 109 appeared 1 times.
The number 125 appeared 1 times.
The number 127 appeared 1 times.
The number 128 appeared 1 times.
The number 74 appeared 1 times.
The number 30 appeared 1 times.
The number 123 appeared 1 times.
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a counter dictionary and append the lines to it as you read over them. Once you finished you can access the key/values using counter.items()

```
from collections import Counter

cntr = Counter()

with open('numbers.txt', 'r') as file_in:
    for line in file_in:
        cntr[line.rstrip()] += 1

for k, v in cntr.items():
    print('Numre of repetitions of %s: is %s' % (k, v))

> Numre of repetitions of 1: is 4
> Numre of repetitions of 3: is 3
> Numre of repetitions of 2: is 2
```

The input numbers.txt file contains:

```
1
2
3
2
3
3
1
1
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking the counts of your numbers is super easy if you use the `collections` module. In it, there is a class named `Counter` that can count any hashable object you can throw at it. In this case, you can give it strings or numbers without a problem. You will need the latest version of Python to use the `f` strings demonstrated here:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import collections


def main():
    with open('numbers.txt', 'rt') as file:
        counts = collections.Counter(map(int, file))
    for key, value in sorted(counts.items()):
        print(f'{key!r} repeats {value!s} times.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```